# How to populate multiple HTML DOM elements with local storage values

Tags: javascript, onclick, local-storage, dom-events

I want to display contents in the last `<div>` element when a click event occurs but now it only shows 1st 2 elements. Is there something I am not doing right somewhere?

- Here is my code so far:

### JS

```js
    const iname = document.getElementById("name");
    const iemail = document.getElementById("email");
    const iphone = document.getElementById("phone");
    const submit = document.getElementById("submit");
    const storage = document.getElementById("storage");
    
    submit.onclick = function () {
    
        const name = iname.value;
        const email = iemail.value;
        const phoneno = iphone.value;
    
        if (name && email && phoneno) {
            localStorage.setItem(name, "");
            localStorage.setItem(email, "");
            localStorage.setItem(phoneno, "");
            location.reload();
        }
    };
    
    for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        const key = localStorage.key(i);
        const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
        storage.innerHTML += `Name : ${key}<br />Email : ${value}`;
    }
    localStorage.clear()
```

### HTML

```html
    <p>Name</p>
    <input id="name" autocomplete="off">
    <p>Email</p>
    <input id="email" autocomplete="off">
    <p>Phone no</p>
    <input id="phone" autocomplete="off">
    <button id="submit">Let's go</button>
    <div id="storage" class="box">
    <h1>Is this correct?</h1></div>
```

Comment: where is that last `<div>` you are talking about in the HTML snippet?

Comment: update,please check @Daniel Dut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are setting the values in `localstorage` the wrong way.

The syntax for storing stuff in there is **`localstorage.setItem(keyName, keyValue)`**.
And your code is setting the `keyName` argument to the value you are getting from the form and  `keyValue` argument to an empty string; not what you need.

Make the following changes and you should be good to go (see comments):

```js
        submit.onclick = function () {
            const name = iname.value;
            const email = iemail.value;
            const phoneno = iphone.value;
        
            if (name && email && phoneno) {
                // set local storage values
                localStorage.setItem("name", name); // modified
                localStorage.setItem("email", email); // modified
                localStorage.setItem("phoneno", phoneno); // modified
                location.reload();
            }
            console.log(localStorage); // new (maybe unnecessary)
        };
        
        for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
            const key = localStorage.key(i);
            const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
            storage.innerHTML += `${upFirst(key)}: ${value}<br>`; // modified
        }
        localStorage.clear();

        /**
         * new: making the first letter an upper case (for labels in the output div).
         * See usage in 'for loop' above.
         */
        function upFirst(stringValue) {
            return stringValue.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + stringValue.slice(1);
        }
```

Comment: I truly appreciate you @Daniel Dut.Thanks again :)